# Android Navigation Drawer over GLSurfaceView

Tags: android

Drawer placed over glSurface behaves wrong. It ignores layout width and height. Animation is bad too.

I took the sample project BasicGLSurfaceView from Android SDK and applied [this official manual](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to it.

If i set glSurface's visibility to `invisible` or remove it and change to any another View everything is okay.

Am i doing something wrong?

UPD1: Just tried to set some solid color as background for drawer. Now it looks acceptable - width and height just as the supposed to be. And the shadow in its place. But animation still twitches.

Comment: Starting from a `NavigationDrawer` activity in Android Studio, and adding the GLSurfaceView later, I have similar problems on a `Galaxy S4` and a `Galaxy Note 10.1` (they differ slightly, though). Did you find a reasonable workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. I was forced to abandon the use of this component. Now i have fixed side panel for large+ screens and transparent fullscreen panel without animation for normal ones. Implemented manually with fragments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DrawerLayout ListView not drawn with GLSurfaceView as content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691012/drawerlayout-listview-not-drawn-with-glsurfaceview-as-content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it solved with workaround described here (just place dummy empty View over GLSurfaceView): [DrawerLayout ListView not drawn with GLSurfaceView as content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691012/drawerlayout-listview-not-drawn-with-glsurfaceview-as-content)