# DrawerLayout ListView not drawn with GLSurfaceView as content

Tags: java, android, listview, opengl-es

My Android app is a fullscreen OpenGL ES 2.0 app, so the main content is a custom extension of GLSurfaceView.
The activity layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I then add my GLSurfaceView using the addView method of the FrameLayout.
If i don't do this, the Drawer works as expected.

The ListView seems to be pulled out correctly when i swipe it in, as i can't interact with the GLSurfaceView anymore until i swipe it back to the left. But it's not displayed at all, like the GLSurfaceView is allways rendered ontop of it.

How do i get a DrawerLayout working with a GLSurfaceView as its content?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've just faced the same problem, and I've found quite a silly workaround for it. This issue seems to only affect DrawerLayouts, and not regular Views. So simply place an empty View over your GLSurfaceView, to mask it away from the Drawer.

Here's my stripped down layout file as a sample for you:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GLSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/glSurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <View 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You sir have earned your reputation, works wonderfully!
A quick note for people who add their `GL View` dynamically: Simply place it in the background when adding to the `ViewGroup` with an index. Like this: `myRelativeLayout.addView(myGlView, 0);`